# google datastore gql query with limit and offset cursors?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

I'm trying to use cursors for large result sets.  The documentation indicates you can use cursors with GQL query using php but i can't seem to get it to work.

Has anybody got this working?  If it doesn't work with GQL query, could somebody show me an example of how to implement this?

```
    $query = $datastore->gqlQuery('SELECT * FROM h_stats WHERE field1 = @parm1 AND date >= @startDate AND date < @endDate LIMIT @limitBy OFFSET @cursor', [
                                  'bindings' => [
                                    'parm1' => '5700305828184064',
                                    'startDate' => '1501545600',
                                    'endDate' => '1501632000',
                                    'limitBy' => 10,
                                    'cursor' => 'CURSOR_STRING_HERE'
                                  ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I couldn't find this possible from a GQL query.  But it's possible from a normal query.

Hope this helps somebody out as the google docs are really bad with examples.

```
$datastore = new Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]); 


    function cursor_paging($datastore, $queryKind, $pageSize, $parm1, $startDate, $endDate, $pageCursor = '')
    {

        $query = $datastore->query()
            ->kind($queryKind)
            ->filter('field1', '=', $parm1)
            ->filter('date', '>=', $startDate)
            ->filter('date', '<', $endDate)
            ->limit($pageSize)
            ->start($pageCursor);       

        $result = $datastore->runQuery($query);
        $nextPageCursor = '';
        $entities = [];

        foreach ($result as $entity) {
            $nextPageCursor = $entity->cursor();
            $entities[] = $entity;
        }
        return array(
            'nextPageCursor' => $nextPageCursor,
            'entities' => $entities
        );

    }
```

This is how i used it with this function that was provided in the google cloud datastore php docs.

```
    $pageSize = 500;
    $queryKind = "your_kind";
    $result = cursor_paging($datastore, $queryKind, $pageSize, $currentThermostat, $startDate, $endDate);

    $countRows = 0;

    for ($x=0; $x < $pageSize; $x++) {

        $counter = 0;

        foreach ($result['entities'] as $item) {
            print($countRows . " " . $item['data']);
            $countRows++;
            $counter++;
        }

        $result = cursor_paging($datastore, $queryKind, $pageSize, $currentThermostat, $startDate, $endDate, $result['nextPageCursor']);

        if ($counter > 0) {
            $x = 0;
        } else {
            $x = $pageSize;  //exit loop when no more results
        }
    }
```